# datagrid view is not showing data

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, sqldatasource

I try this code for showing some info from sql database. but I can not see the datas in gridview..How can I solve?? Also, I have no error.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Server=CAN-PC; Database=SMS; UID=SA;  PWD=delidana1963");
    string sql = "";
    sql = @"select Orginator,RecordDate, (select COUNT(TurkcellID) from SmsStore ";

 //   txttarih.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
    var tarih1 = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date);
    var tarih2 = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", Calendar2.SelectedDate.Date);


    if (Calendar1.SelectedDate != null && Calendar2.SelectedDate != null)
        sql += "where RecordDate between '" +tarih1 + "' and  '" + tarih2 + "'";
    else if (Calendar1.SelectedDate != null && Calendar2.SelectedDate == null)
        sql += "where RecordDate between '" + tarih1 + "' and '" + DateTime.Now + "'";
    sql += ") as toplammsj,";

    sql += "(select COUNT(TurkcellID) from SmsStore where TurkcellID=1 ";
    if (Calendar1.SelectedDate != null && Calendar2.SelectedDate != null)
        sql += "and RecordDate between '" + tarih1 + "' and '" + tarih2+ "'";
    else if (Calendar1.SelectedDate != null && Calendar2.SelectedDate == null)
        sql += "and RecordDate between '" + tarih1 + "' and '" + DateTime.Now + "'";
    sql += ") as giden,";

    sql += " (select COUNT(TurkcellID) from SmsStore where TurkcellID=0 ";
    if (Calendar1.SelectedDate != null && Calendar2.SelectedDate != null)
        sql += "and RecordDate between '" + tarih1 + "' and '" + tarih2 + "'";
    else if (Calendar1.SelectedDate != null && Calendar2.SelectedDate == null)
        sql += "and RecordDate between '" + tarih1 + "' and '" + DateTime.Now + "'";
    sql += ") as gitmeyen from SmsStore ";

    if (Calendar1.SelectedDate != null && Calendar2.SelectedDate != null)
        sql += "where RecordDate between '" + tarih1+ "' and '" + tarih2 + "'";
    else if (Calendar1.SelectedDate != null && Calendar2.SelectedDate == null)
        sql += "where RecordDate between '" + tarih1 + "' and '" + DateTime.Now + "'";

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.DataMember = "dt";
}
```

please help me about this problem.
thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a [WPF GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx)  or a [Windows Forms DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)? The WPF GridView does not have a DataSource property or DataBind() method. And for a DataGridView, you do not need to use DataBind() or set the DataMember property if the **DataSource** is a DataTable, as you have done.

Also, for debugging purposes put a breakpoint after the line `adp.Fill(dt)`. Put your cursor over `dt` and examine the properties to determine if Rows.Count is greater than 0. If your SQL is messed up, you might not be getting any data from the database in the first place.

Comment: I put break point and the Rows.Count is 6 so greater than 0. Also I use  <asp:GridView ... /> What can I do?